# Access qrpython images without writing them to file

Tags: python, qr-code

Here's my problem.

I'm building a simple QR-code generator with qrcode and PyQt4. In particular, this application shows an image of the generated QR-code inside a `QPixmap` of a `QLabel`. The problem is that the `qrmodule`, as far as I know, allows only to save the generated image to a file. I tried to access the *inner workings* of `qrcode` but it's kind of convoluted.

Do you know if it's possible to expose the image by saving the resulting image in a file stream, like the one from `tempfile.TemporaryFile()`? Otherwise I can only insert the qr-code by saving it on a real file and then loading it. For example

```
import qrcode as q
from PyQt4 import QtGui

filename = 'path/to/file.png'
img = q.make('Data')
img.save(filename)

pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(filename)
```

---

EDIT 1

I tried to use the `PIL.ImageQt.ImageQt` function as proposed in an answer in the following way

```
import sys
import qrcode as qr
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PIL import ImageQt

a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
l = QtGui.QLabel()
pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt.ImageQt(qr.make("Some test data")))
l.setPixmap(pix)
l.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

The result is not however consistent. This is the result obtained using the method above

[image: Damaged QR code]

And this is the result using `qrcode.make('Some test data').save('test2.png')`

[image: Good QR code]

Am I missing something? The `ImageQt` function si a subclass of `QImage` as far as I understand, in fact I get no runtime errors, but the image is corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it takes a couple of steps to do this but you don't need to mess around with intermediate files. Note that the QRcode that `qrcode` generates is a PIL (python image library but its best to use the fork pillow) object. PIL provides the handy `ImageQt` module to convert your QR code into an `Qimage` object. Next you need to use the method `QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage` to create a pixmap (this method seg faults unless qt's initialisation has been done). The complete code would look something like this:

```
>>> import qrcode as q
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> from PIL import ImageQt
>>> import sys
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) # line 8 seg faults without this
>>> qrcode = q.make("some test data")
>>> qt_image = ImageQt.ImageQt(qrcode)
>>> pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qt_image)
```

Obviously you can neaten that up somewhat but it works.

Comment: This is pointing to the right way I think, but it doesn't work as hoped for. See my edit 1 for details.

Comment: @mmassaro. Thats really weird. I'll do some more digging then.

Comment: @mmassaro This method works with pillow images created with the `Image.open` method (i.e. those backed by a real PNG) although this doesn't help you much. I think the `ImageQt.ImageQt` method doesn't like PIL objects created dynamically for some reason.